# convert PostgreSQL column type `text[]` to Oracle

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle, asp.net-web-api, types

I have a table in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
    name            text,
    floor           text[]
);
```

**sample data :**

```
name = 'CSE', floor = ['1-A', 1-B', '2-A'];
name = 'EEE', floor = ['2-B', '3-A'];
```

I want to convert the table in Oracle, I need help for the second column.
What is Oracle equivalent of `TEXT[]` ?

I have some requirements:

1. (If Oracle has any) I want to make my array type `string[]` (I mean `TEXT[]`) . I don't want to have any scope of pushing `INT` into the array.
2. (If possible) please try not to use `raw(200)` or `byte(200)`, since I want my type strictly `string`.
3. Suggest me also If I can make a array of `VARCHAR2(200)`

[ **Note:**

I used .NET Core for API before, So,

```
string name;
string[] floor;
```

was fine for PostgreSQL, I don't want to change my API code, I just want a `string[]` equivalent type for Oracle (or `int[]` based on when I need to use what) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a table in Oracle with a nested table as a column

```
create type string_tbl is table of varchar2(200);
/

create table department (
  name varchar2(10),
  floor string_tbl
)
nested table floor store as floor_tbl;
/

insert into department( name, floor )
  values( 'CSE', string_tbl( '1-A', '1-B', '2-A' ) );
```

It rarely makes sense to define a data model this way, however.  It almost always makes more sense to have a separate `floor` table and a `department_floor` mapping table to map departments to floors (I assume that a single floor can have multiple departments).  Particularly if you are trying to support multiple databases with the same code base.  Supporting different dialects of SQL is hard enough without introducing things like nested tables which tend to have *very* different semantics in different databases.

Comment: thanks for your implementation, but seriously? Oracle doesn't have a dedicated type for string array? I really have to create a type for it? Its so funny that their db has to be that dumb lol.

Comment: @Frost - If it bothers you, you could reuse one of the types that is defined elsewhere for some other purpose (I've got 400+ collection types defined in the `sys` schema in 19c for example).  It's just conventional to define your own type so that if you subsequently decide that you want `varchar2(250)` rather than `varchar2(200)` you can make the change without impacting other tables.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PostgresSQL to Oracle migration tools and services](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql-to-oracle), `text` is a

> Variable-length character data, ⇐ 1G

and is to be "migrated" to `CLOB` datatype in Oracle.

Though, values you presented are way *smaller* so I guess that `VARCHAR2` might do, e.g. `varchar2(100)`.

Comment: if (postgres) `text` is `clob` (oracle) then what should be (postgres) `text[]` for oracle?

Comment: That would be an array / collection. You'd implement it as a nested table (as Justin showed in his answer). I prefer creating a separate *detail* table which is related to its *master* via foreign key constraint.